Issue with notation after replacing dot for a comma
I import data from a system. The manual input (production) is not always the same. Sometimes they use a dot, sometimes a comma.
I need to transpose these values to numbers, for calculations.
With my code, I see 3 thing going wrong.

the values without decimals, are the only values I can use for calculations

the values with a dot, are after conversions aligned to the left, and cannot be used for calculations

the values that were good at the start, are now also aligned to the left, and cannot be used as numbers.


How can I get all values into "number" format with 1 decimal?
Below the code:
Sub notation()

    Columns("B:B").Select

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True, _
        ReplaceFormat:=True, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub

When I change the format, and replace "," for "." manually in Excel, the new format is correct.
